# Rephrasing the sentences

Tags: word-choice

In how many ways  would you rephrase these sentences?

> When my cat went missing I was a wreck.
>
> When my cat went missing I was beside myself with worry.

The purpose of each sentence is twofold:  to describe the cat owner's feelings, and to make the sentence as emotional as possible.

Comment: When my cat went missing I was worried sick.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you asking for a whole series of paraphrases (which I'm sure would be contrary to this website's intended purposes), or a comment on your two versions?

Comment: No, only for rephrasng/comments on  my two vesrions.

Comment: Surely there are only two ways of saying that, your form and reversed: "I was a wreck when my cat went missing". Unless you go for Yoda-speak, "When my cat went missing, a wreck I was," which is hardly commonplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to rephrase a sentence, and at the same time maintain its original message. I'll limit my answer to the  first sentence.

> When my cat went missing I was a wreck.

You could add a comma after *missing*.

> When my cat went missing **,** I was a wreck.

You could invert the two clauses; in which case no comma is needed.

> I was a wreck when my cat went missing.

You could add an adjective before the noun, cat.

> When my ***white*** cat went missing, I was a wreck

You could add an extra adjective.

> When my ***cherished*** white cat went missing, I was a wreck

You could add another adjective before *wreck*.

> When my cherished cat went missing, I was a ***nervous*** wreck.

You could choose to add a noun, known as a [*noun adjunct*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), before *wreck*.

> When my cherished cat went missing, I was a ***walking*** wreck.

You could add a *subordinating conjunction*, [like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Like), before the dependent clause, "a walking wreck".

> When my cherished cat went missing, I was ***like*** a walking wreck

You could add an adverb of time either at the beginning or the end of the first clause.

> When my cherished cat went missing ***last week***, I was a nervous
>   wreck.

You could add the cat's name, as a personal touch, so readers would feel a greater affinity towards it.

> When my cherished cat, ***snowball***, went missing last week; I was a
>   nervous wreck.

And I would stop there before the sentence sounds too artificial and long winded! :)

Comment: Thank you very much, MARI-LOU A for your answer. :) I think I could also say 'I was frantic' or 'frantic  with worry'.

Comment: Yes, you can say "I was frantic (with worry)" I quite like that expression, myself. :)

Comment: The owner of the cat is me, and to be honest, I don't  think there is such a word  that can describe what an animal parent feels when something happens to their pets. But I really   like rephrasing sentences and I am always looking for different  versions.

Comment: Well I guessed the cat in the phrase might be cherished, and you have confirmed it to be so (I hope your cat is OK now).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and Edwin Ashworth's question, I'll suggest a couple of versions for each exemplar, but I'll add a few words here and there, since you did not specifically say not to.

> "To say the least, I was a complete wreck when my cat went missing."
>
> "My cat went missing just before the 'Miss Meow Competition'; consequently, I was an emotional wreck."
>
> "I was beside myself with worry when my cat went missing."
>
> "To say I was beside myself with worry when my cat went missing would be to engage in understatement!"
>
> "My cat went missing; I was a wreck."
>
> "My cat went missing; I was beside myself with worry."
>
> "When my cat went missing, I remained in a catatonic state for a good five minutes."

My point is (if in fact there is a unifying element in my versions):  what is the purpose of your sentence?  Or, how does does it fit between what came before and after?  Or, what mood are you trying to set?  Or, who is your audience?  If your audience is kids, then you'd probably not use your example two or my example seven, because kids would understand neither "beside myself with worry" nor "a catatonic state."

Since this website is about English usage, you need to develop your question a bit more.  Tell us what's bothering you--if anything--about the sentences you provided.  Do you have grammatical concerns?  Do you wonder which sentence may communicate better with a specific audience?  Do you have stylistic concerns regarding your word choices?  And so on.

Comment: The purpose of my sentence was to describe the cat owner's feelings and make the sentence as emotional as possible.

Comment: Like the typical stereotypical guy (aka, male of the species, Neanderthal, male chauvinist pig), I simply was not tuned into your emotional frequency.  Guess I'm not as good at reading between the lines as someone from the distaff side!

Comment: Even if you weren't turned into my emotional frequency, as you say it doesn't matter. You suggested a few interesting versions and that's what I was looking for. Thanks for your reply.